# How to import CSV in Neo4j and replacing null values, with default value?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, null, cypher

I am trying to import two quite similar CSV files but I have issues changing the null value to a default value. This is my code so far:

I have tried coalesce and foreach.
But I am not sure that I used it correctly.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Company.csv' AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH toInteger(row.CompanyID) AS CID, row.CompanyName AS CompanyName, row.Street AS Street, 
row.PostalCodeCity AS PostalCodeCity, row.Country AS Country, row.MainPhone AS MainPhone, 
row.Website AS Website, row.VATnumber AS VATnumber, toInteger(row.MarketCode) AS MarketCode, 
toInteger(row.SecondaryCode) AS SecondaryCode, row.Market AS Market, row.Status AS Status
MERGE (c:Company {Street: coalesce(row.Street, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {PostalCodeCity: coalesce(row.PostalCodeCity, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {MainPhone: coalesce(row.MainPhone, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {Website: coalesce(row.Website, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {VATnumber: coalesce(row.VATnumber, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {MarketCode: coalesce(row.MarketCode, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {SecondaryCode: coalesce(row.SecondaryCode, "Unknown")})
Merge (c:Company {CID: CID})
RETURN count(c)
```

I expect to get the same output as when I only see the CSV file, which is working. But when I use MERGE it can't handle null values, and therefore I want to replace them.

Right now I get a Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `row` not defined (line 7, column 36 (offset: 479))
"MERGE (c:Company {Street: coalesce(row.Street, "Unknown")})"
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are renaming variables in the WITH statemt, but thr using the original variables in merges...

Try

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Company.csv' 
AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH toInteger(row.CompanyID) AS CID, 
row.CompanyName AS CompanyName, row.Street AS 
Street, 
row.PostalCodeCity AS PostalCodeCity, row.Country AS 
Country, row.MainPhone AS MainPhone, 
row.Website AS Website, row.VATnumber AS VATnumber, 
toInteger(row.MarketCode) AS MarketCode, 
toInteger(row.SecondaryCode) AS SecondaryCode, 
row.Market AS Market, row.Status AS Status
MERGE (c:Company {Street: coalesce(Street, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {PostalCodeCity: coalesce(PostalCodeCity, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {MainPhone: coalesce(MainPhone, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {Website: coalesce(Website, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {VATnumber: coalesce(VATnumber, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {MarketCode: coalesce(MarketCode, "Unknown")})
MERGE (c:Company {SecondaryCode: coalesce(SecondaryCode, "Unknown")})
Merge (c:Company {CID: CID})
RETURN count(c)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but changed the error, now I am wondering why I get the error which is that the ID is null throughout the code, and in the CSV file the ID is set for them all.

Comment: Would you be able to help with adding labels on the nodes and merge them into one tabel instead of one element for each.